# C.....Shufling values of linked list

Tags: c, random, linked-list, playing-cards

I am writing a war cards game. I need to shufle first few elements of players hand (linked list).
That`s what i have:

```
void tasowanie(llist_t** head, int warsize) {
    llist_t** temp = head;
    Card_t temp_card;
    int random;

    while (warsize > 0) {
        random = rand() % warsize;
        for (int j = 0; j < random; j++)
            if ((*temp)!=NULL && (*temp)->next != NULL)
                *temp = (*temp)->next;
        temp_card = (*head)->card;
        (*head)->card = (*temp)->card;
        (*temp)->card = temp_card;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        *temp = *head;
        warsize--;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am losing elements of this list.
I was thinking about puting these elements into array, then shufling it and puting it back to the list, although I imagine there has to be more elegant solution.

Comment: You could try swapping the data instead of the linkage, which is arguably more elegant and less prone to error.

Comment: That`s what I am doing

Comment: But i still need to get to a random .next.next.... and that is the place where i am losing elements

Comment: You might also consider abandoning a linked list in favor of a structure that's easier to shuffle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be writing to `*temp`, as this is a pointer to the real list `next` pointer.

The same applies to moving `head`: unless you intend to update the list you should not be touching `*head`.

Instead, when you want to update `temp` you should set it with `temp = &((*temp)->next)`, and reset with `temp=head`.

```
void tasowanie(llist_t** head, int warsize) {
    llist_t** temp = head;
    Card_t temp_card;
    int random;

    while (warsize > 0) {
        random = rand() % warsize;
        for (int j = 0; j < random; j++)
            if ((*temp)!=NULL && (*temp)->next != NULL)
                temp = &((*temp)->next);
        temp_card = (*head)->card;
        (*head)->card = (*temp)->card;
        (*temp)->card = temp_card;
        head = &((*head)->next);
        temp = head;
        warsize--;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow aren't you writer of C++ Concurreny(modern) ?? +1 by the way

Comment: Yes, I am the author of *C++ Concurrency in Action*

Comment: It looks like I should buy your book haha

Comment: That's why I posted my first comment: I thought the pointers were being swapped.